# Shared Widening Operator CType Not being called

Tags: vb.net

Suppose I have the following code:

```
Public Class MyDbTransaction
    Implements IDbTransaction

     Private itsTransaction As IDbTransaction
     Public Sub New(ByVal trans As IDbTransaction)
        If trans Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("trans")

        itsTransaction = trans
     End Sub

     Public ReadOnly Property Base As IDbTransaction
        Get
            Return itsTransaction
        End Get
    End Property

     <...all the other implementations go here...>

     Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal trans As MyDbTransaction) As SqlTransaction
        If trans Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        Else
            Return CType(trans.Base, SqlTransaction)
        End If
    End Operator
End Class
```

If Somewhere in my code I do:

```
   Dim conn as New MyConnection(New SqlClient.SqlConnection("<ConnectionStringHere>"))
   Dim Trn as IDbTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
   Dim Cmd As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand = CreateCommand(SqlText, Cnn, Trn)
   Cmd.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout
   Cmd.Transaction = Trn  'Trn is of type MyDbTransaction and IT CRASHES HERE but I am expecting it to call MyDbTransaction.<Widening Operator CType(ByVal trans As MyDbTransaction) As SqlTransaction> to resolve this cast'
```

The last line crashes with:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MyDbTransaction' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction'
```

Why doesn't it invoke the Widening operator here?

### **PER AakashM: This is how the transaction object is created in MyConnection **

```
Public Class MyConnection
    Implements IDbConnection

      Private itsConnection As IDbConnection
      Protected Sub New(ByVal conn As IDbConnection)
          If conn Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("conn")

          itsConnection = conn
      End Sub

      Public Overridable Function BeginTransaction() As IDbTransaction Implements IDbConnection.BeginTransaction
        return New MyDbTransaction(itsConnection.BeginTransaction())
      End Function

      Public Overridable Function BeginTransaction(ByVal il As IsolationLevel) As IDbTransaction Implements IDbConnection.BeginTransaction
        return New MyDbTransaction(itsConnection.BeginTransaction(il))
      End Function

      <...all the other implementations go here...>
End Class
```

Comment: what happens if you use `CType(Trn, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction)` instead of just setting the Transaction to Trn?

Comment: @Nicholas doesn't work. If I change to "narrowing" then your statement work

Comment: Show us where you create `Trn`. In particular, what you pass into the ctor as `trans`.

Comment: @AakashM: See modified description above

Comment: It does invoke the operator.  When then bombs because you cannot cast MyDbTransaction to SqlTransaction.  The constructor argument *trans* must be of type SqlTransaction, nothing else can work.

Comment: @Hans: It doesn't invoke the "Widening Operator CType" because if I put a breakpoint there (see code above) it doesn't break there. I am writing the "Widening" operator exactly for that purpose because this class can't cast to "SqlTransaction" so I am telling it how to cast to SqlTransaction.

Comment: I certainly invoked the operator when I tried your code.  The only thing you achieved with the operator is to stop the compiler from telling you that you did it wrong.  You are stuck with SqlTransaction, you cannot customize it.

Comment: You can't cast it because MyDbTransaction is not a SqlTransaction.  It would have worked if SqlCommand.Transaction would have accepted an IDbTransaction.  But it doesn't, it wants a SqlTransaction, no substitute is accepted.  Only that class knows how to properly implement transactions on SQL Server.  You wrote this code to try to work around that restriction but it can't work.

Comment: @HansPassant: But if I change the operator above to "Narrowing" and use Cmd.Transaction = CType(Trn, SqlClient.SqlTransaction) then everything works fine. I am just trying to find a way not to use "CType" (because legacy code doesn't have it and it's in many places). I would like to find a way for it to do the same thing as Narrowing does but implicitly. Do you see what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation that I can come up with for why it doesn't work is that your class is not inheriting from SqlTransaction, thus does not inherit the members, and as such, can't be converted to the base implementation of SqlTransaction.

This [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1e94s7e.aspx) explains this indirectly:

"It might seem surprising that a conversion from a derived type to one of its base types is widening. The justification is that the derived type contains all the members of the base type, so it qualifies as an instance of the base type. In the opposite direction, the base type does not contain any new members defined by the derived type."

Because your class implements IDbTransaction, you would successfully be able to assign to any property that expects this Interface, but because it does not inherit SqlTransaction, you may not assign it to any property or parameter that expects SqlTransaction.

I think that it would make much more sense to either inherit from SqlTransaction or to use [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) to implement your desired functionality.

Comment: SqlTransaction is SEALED and can't be inherited. We are still using .NET 2.0 so Extension Methods are not available nor would they be able to fill the need as things need to happen in this class at creation - I don't believe you can mimic that with extension methods not would you be able to override some methods.

Comment: Sorry, I should have looked at the transaction implementation before suggesting this as an option. What additional functionality are you trying to implement?

Comment: competent_tech. I would like to track who created the transaction, if it has any sub-transaction associated with it, I would like it to raise an event when it is completed. Just some of the things...

Comment: @Denis: I am out of ideas on how to extend the class, but the way that we handle this type of need is that we wrap all of the database functionality in an object we call DBHelper (originally from the MS Enterprise Library). If code wants to work with a transaction, it calls methods on this class, which in turn uses the underlying transaction object. By controlling all of the DB activity this way, we can do whatever we need when transactions are started, completed, etc. This also allows us to, if needed, automatically rollback open transactions when connection is closed, etc.